# probability, expectation, variance

Tags: statistics, random-variables, expectation, covariance

A 10-digit long number is picked randomly and each digit's pick is independent and has an equal probability of being picked (1/9 because there's digits 1 to 9).

Let $X = \#\{\text{missing digits}\}$ (i.e. if the # is 1357768931, X = 2 because there's no 2 or 4)

What is E(X)? Var(X)?

I am so confused as to how to start this. Some guidance please?

Comment: what about digit 0?

Answer (score 1):

We assume on the uncertain basis of hints in the wording that for some reason the digit $0$ is forbidden. In order to avoid computing probabilities, we use the method of *indicator* random variables, and exploit the linearity of expectation.

For $i=1$ to $9$, let $X_i=1$ if digit $i$ is missing, and let $X_i=0$ otherwise. Then the number $X$ of missing digits is $X_1+\cdots+X_9$.

We have $E(X_1+\cdots+X_9)=E(X_1)+\cdots +E(X_9)=9E(X_1)$.
The probability that the digit $1$ is missing is $\left(\frac{8}{9}\right)^{10}$. Thus the required expectation is $9\cdot \left(\frac{8}{9}\right)^{10}$.

For the variance, it will all be easy once we know $E(X^2)$, that is, $E((X_1+\cdots+X_9)^2)$.

Expand the square. We get $X_1^2+\cdots+X_9^2$, plus a bunch of mixed terms.

It is easy to calculate $E(X_1^2+\cdots+X_9^2)$, indeed we have already done so, since $X_i^2=X_i$.

There are $(9)(8)$ "mixed" terms $X_iX_j$ where $i\ne j$. We find $E(X_iX_j)$. This is $\left(\frac{7}{9}\right)^{10}$, since with probability $\frac{7}{9}$ a digit in a specified position  in the list of $10$ is neither $i$ nor $j$. Now put the pieces together.

**Remark:** The method can be adapted to "real" $10$-digit numbers, where $0$ is allowed, except as the first digit. But then $X_1$ is "special" and things get somewhat more complicated, less symmetrical.

Comment: Are you sure that the $X_i$'s are independent? If $X_1=1$ then doesn't that change the probability for $X_2$?

Comment: @Duncan:   I am sure they are **not independent**.  The linearity of expectation does not require independence. That is what gives the method of indicator random variables much of its power.

Comment: Oh, duh. Thanks for the reminder of something I should already know. Always feel silly when I forget something so fundamental.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to note: the range of $X$ is $\{0,1,\ldots,8\}$. Second thing to note: there are $9^{10}$ possible 10-digit numbers. Then the expectation is given by
\begin{align}
E(X) &= \sum_{x=0}^8xP(X=x)\\
&= \sum_{x=0}^8 x\left(\frac{\#\mbox{ 10-digit numbers with exactly }x\mbox{ missing digits}}{9^{10}}\right).
\end{align}
Then you have to compute the numerator for all values of $x$. A few ones are straight-forward: how many with no missing digit? How many with 8 missing digits? Can you do all of them?

Finally, to compute the variance, you can do as above to compute $E(X^2)$, and then use the fact that
$$Var(X) = E(X^2) - E(X)^2.$$